# How to get the file_id of a wopi host integration?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I've deployed a Wopi client as mentioned in the documentation and now i'm trying to deploy a wopi host, but i'm new to .net enviroment and i don't know how to get the file hosted in wopi-docs folder. (It seems to be encrypted but i don't know how to get the files in that folder)

I have done the next steps:

1. I implemented an office online server according [the official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server#deploy-the-office-online-server-farm) (Wopi client)
2. I tried the discovery URL and it worked perfectly.
3. I deployed a wopi host according to [this repo.](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost) (Wopi host and a great repo by the way)
4. Cloned the repo in the server.
5. I removed Cobalt project from solution [from command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln#remove) in the root directory.
6. I [rebuilt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean) the solution [from command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) in the root directory.
7. I [ran](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) WopiHost project from command line in the WopiHost directory.
8. I [ran](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) WopiHost.Web project from command line in the WopiHost.Web directory.
9. I tried Wopi integration with a [wopi host page](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hostpage.html#working-around-browser-iframe-behavior) (i don't know if it's correct, but at least it seems to work partially) like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Enable IE Standards mode -->
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://my-server-url.com/wv/resources/1033/FavIcon_Word.ico" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            -ms-content-zooming: none;
        }

        #office_frame {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: none;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="office_form" name="office_form" target="office_frame" action="https://my-server-url.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?ui=es-mx&rs=es-mx&dchat=1&showpagestats=1&IsLicensedUser=1&WOPISrc=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-server-url.com%3A5000%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2Ftest.docx" method="post">
        <input name="access_token" value="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxMjM0NSIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiQW5vbnltb3VzIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhbm9ueW1vdXNAZG9tYWluLnRsZCIsIlVzZXJQZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6IlVzZXJDYW5BdHRlbmQsIFVzZXJDYW5QcmVzZW50LCBVc2VyQ2FuUmVuYW1lLCBVc2VyQ2FuV3JpdGUiLCJuYmYiOjE2MTA2MDU5NDgsImV4cCI6MTYxMDYwOTU0OCwiaWF0IjoxNjEwNjA1OTQ4fQ.KbxGcTVOa3yWCGcEHEGv9MRP_NskfViW_vyMTOupRO4" type="hidden" />
        <input name="access_token_ttl" value="0" type="hidden" />
    </form>

    <span id="frameholder"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var frameholder = document.getElementById('frameholder');
        var office_frame = document.createElement('iframe');
        office_frame.name = 'office_frame';
        office_frame.id = 'office_frame';

        // The title should be set for accessibility
        office_frame.title = 'Office Frame';

        // This attribute allows true fullscreen mode in slideshow view
        // when using PowerPoint's 'view' action.
        office_frame.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', 'true');

        // The sandbox attribute is needed to allow automatic redirection to the O365 sign-in page in the business user flow
        office_frame.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-top-navigation allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox');
        frameholder.appendChild(office_frame);

        document.getElementById('office_form').submit();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And the result that i get is the following error:
[image]

Does anyone know how to get the correct name of the files to put into the html file above or how do i get the wopi host web?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Office online server uses the WOPISrc query string which is passed from the WOPI Host Page. Check the implementation of GetCheckFileInfo and GetFile in WOPI Host and see if it is able to acces the file provided in the query string. var file = StorageProvider.GetWopiFile(id)

Answer (score 0):

The file ID in my repo is just [base64 encoded](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/1322427ffd28926e8c3159cdebd0d3825487dc21/WopiHost.FileSystemProvider/WopiFileSystemProvider.cs#L104-L114). To verify that you're using the correct path, just take the base64 value and pass it to a [decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) or write your own utility to decode it.
The ID should be opaque to the WOPI client (Office Online Server) - it accepts it an passess it back to the WOPI host which can undertand it and return the right file.
I recommend putting breakpoints to GetCheckFileInfo and GetFile methods to see if they're being hit correctly and what data they return.